# how to delete files in different linux servers on a given path?

Tags: shell-script

This is my script and i am using here to list the files on a give path by the user,it is logging into the server but not listing the files, can any one has any idea?

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Please give correct path"
for HOST in $(cat servers.txt ) ; do
    ssha $HOST < List.sh
done
```

cat List.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter the path to list the files"
read $path
ls -lrt
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you're passing the script via stdin, but the script itself tries to read from stdin. In order to pass parameters to the script passed on stdin, I'd recommend using command line arguments, possibly with a read-from-stdin in the external loop if you still need that.

The second-order problem you have is that your syntax for the `read` call is wrong. (It takes a variable name without a `$`.) Also, you want to pass `-r` to `read`, or else it'll do nasty and unexpected things if the input contains a backslash.

The third-order problem you have is you're doing `for i in $(cat servers.txt)`, when instead you want `<servers.txt while read -r i`. That goes linewise; the `for` loop not only reads the entire file into memory (making it possibly blow up on large files), it fails when individual lines have whitespace in them.

Comment: ssh: Could not resolve hostname ls: Name or service not known
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ls: Name or service not known      this is the error i am getting when i run above script

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several issues going on here.  One of them is you are trying to prompt the user within the ssh session on the remote server, but because you are redirecting that script via stdin to the ssh session, there is no terminal allocated and not much opportunity for the user to respond.

Then, you're reading from `stdin`, but that's actually the stream that contains the rest of the script, so it's just reading the from the lines you want it to execute, not user input.

Then you're trying to expand the variable `$path` as the argument to read, but you should not have the `$` as you just give it the name of the variable, you don't have to expand the name of it (as with any place you set a variable).

Finally, you never try to use that path in your `ls` command.

Probably, you would be better off in this case prompting the user before executing the script.  Something like:

```
while read -r host; do
    read -p "Enter the path to list the files: " path
    ssh $HOST ls -lrt $path
done < servers.txt
```